# Output Mosaic Dataset seamline feature class removing overlapping areas?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mosaic-dataset

I have a mosaic dataset of 50+ images with large areas of overlap. I would like to create a feature class of the VISIBLE FOOTPRINTS of the dataset based on the mosaicking stacking order e.g. "NorthWest" or "By Attribute". I can generate a seamline with the "SOrder" attribute but what I want is a feature class of polygons with no areas of overlap showing just the footprints of the visible imagery.